# Objective-C can't play sound with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I am using XCode 7 with iOS 9 and I am trying to play a sound. I have been googling for a solution for days and I have tried every possible solution out there and nothing is working.

Here is my code

.h

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <DTDeviceDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{

}
```

and here is my .m file:

```
 NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"autumn_leaves" ofType:@"m4a"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSError *error;

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                                   error:&error];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

    [player play];
```

and no sound, no errors, no warnings nothing at all

`soundFilePath` and `soundFileURL` are not `nil`, same with player, they are getting populated. My phone volume is as loud as it can be.

I have also tried in .m file:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;

self.myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
[self.myPlayer play];
```

Also did not play sound and no errors.

Here is a screenshot of my Resources folder:

[image]

Please Help!

Comment: Try using .caf file instead of any other type. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Define AVAudioPlayer as a property, and it should work. 
You could implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate if you want, its not a must.

For detailed explanation check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8415802/1789203

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong)AVAudioPlayer *player;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bush_god_bless" ofType:@"wav"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSError *error;

    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                                   error:&error];
    self.player.numberOfLoops = 0; //Infinite
    self.player.delegate  = self;
    [self.player play];


}
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"%d",flag);
}
```

Comment: I believe numberOfLoops = 0 means play once. If you want infinite playback so any negative number as documented here by Apple https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1386071-numberofloops

Answer (score 0):

You need to set delegate to self before [player play];

```
player.delegate  = self;
[player play];
```